# Baire property and perfect set

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

**Be $A\subset X$ whit the Baire property and not meager. Show that $A$ contain a subset perfect nonempty.**

I try prove that $A$ contain a subset $G_{\delta}$ no-numerable and use the theorem of Cantor Bendixson. But I cannot to show that $A$ contains a subset $G_{\delta}$ no-numerable...

Comment: $X$ Is a Polish space.

Comment: $X$ [should be perfect](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1628181/212120) for this to work.